# How to make autocomplete text box by select box in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select box by which i select state of a country. but i want a text box where i type name of state , then list of state appear by matched input text i.e. autocomplete. e.g When i type "lon" then dropdown show london etc.

```
<select id="state" name="cBillState" class="selectbox2">
   <?php print $db->stateDropDown($detail[cBillState]); ?>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/)**.

```
<head>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $(".select2").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="select2">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

You can download the select2.css and select2.js files from here http://select2.github.io/select2/

After including the files and initiating the select2() function, all you would then need to do is use a **select2** class on any select fields you need the filter on.

This code uses jQuery to initiate the select2() function. You can initiate it with plain javascript if you aren't using jQuery.